# Как настроить список ссылок в TinyMCE 4 - link_list

Tags: tinymce

В скрипте есть такое:

```
link_list: "/admin.php?name=pages&action=showlist_js"
```

Данная ссылка выводит массив внутренних страниц в виде:

```
{title: 'Опросы', value: '/about/poll/'},
{title: 'Контакты', value: '/about/contacts/'}
```

однако в редакторе, при выборе внутренней ссылки для вставки, список ссылок не выводятся.

Как можно настроить это?